# Extend python enum in __new__ with auto()

Tags: python, enums, auto

I have a question related to using auto() with python enum.

I have a base clase like this:

```
class TokenEnum(IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        member = object.__new__(cls)

        # Always auto-generate the int enum value
        member._value_ = auto()  # << not working !!

        member.rule = value
        return member
```

and want to use it like this. The enum value should be an int and auto-generated. The string provided should go into the additional 'rule' variable.

```
class Tokens(TokenEnum):
    ID = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    ...
```

`auto()` doesn't seem to work in the place where I'm using it. And idea on how to get this working?

Comment: Can't you just write `member._value_ = 0`?

Comment: @mkrieger: I need a unique int value per enum entry. A static value would not work.

Comment: I *think* the right thing to do is to define a static method named [`_generate_next_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._generate_next_value_), which `auto` (whatever that is) uses to generate a new value.

Comment: @chepner: please see enum.py line 173. That is where `class auto:` is defined (in 3.11). So yes, it is a class. It seems work as a placeholder.

Comment: @Juergen Thank you, I thought I was going insane. (Long story short, GitHub is painfully slow on my ancient computer, I was looking at `Lib/enum.py` in a local checkout I have on disk, which for reasons unknown to me had a commit from 2015 checked out as a detached head. Checked out `main`, and there it was :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` is resolved before `__new__` is called -- it should only be used on the member assignment line (i.e. `ID = auto()`).

If you need `TokenEnum` members to be integers, you'll want:

```
def __new__(cls, value):
    int_value_ = len(cls.__members__) + 1   # numbering usually starts at 1
    member = int.__new__(cls, int_value)    # use int, not object
    member._value_ = int_value
    member.rule = value
    return member
```

If they don't need to be integers, but you want the value to be an integer, you can do:

```
def __new__(cls, value):
    int_value_ = len(cls.__members__) + 1   # numbering usually starts at 1
    member = object.__new__(cls)            # use object, not int
    member._value_ = int_value              # but assign the int value to _value_
    member.rule = value
    return member
```

If you don't need the value to be an integer, but you do need the `rule` attribute:

```
def __new__(cls, value):
    member = object.__new__(cls)            # use object, not int
    member._value_ = value
    member.rule = value
    return member
```

Finally, if you want to just use the enum as if it were a string:

```
class Tokens(str, Enum):
    ID = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

re.match(ID, some_target_string)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I think you forgot the class argument for your `__new__` calls.